# How can I refresh user access token without requiring the user to log in again?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

The long-lived-access-token expires in 60 days. We need to renew this token before it will be expired. We tried to follow the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived
It looks like calling the API endpoint with "fb_exchange_token" parameter generates new token but it has exactly the same expiration date as the old one.

Can you please provide the correct way of renewing access token?

Comment: It is not possible. If it was there would be very little reason to expire them at all.

Comment: Thanks. However the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived/) says: 

"These tokens are refreshed once per day, when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers." 

It does not look like it is correct, because after investigating our tokens and making several requests per day, the tokens have still the same expiration date as when they were created.... any idea? Also, out app is using "Advance permissions" for some things, to get the insights of the campaigns.

Comment: Which SDK are you using the iOS, Android or Javascript SDK?

Comment: I am not using SDK, I just simply call Graph API... Doesn't all SDKs call the same API endpoints?

Comment: No. The text specifically tell you that the access token is only extended if you use the iOS, Android and Javascript SDKs. And that is because those SDKs can make sure that the user is actually doing something. Having your server send a request to Facebook server doesn't require the user to do anything.